# Where do I need to write in an output function in my code?

Tags: c, file, bubble-sort

For a task I got a text file with integers in it. There can be a different number of integers in each line, but it can't be more than 30. All integers in the file are separated by spaces. I need to write code which sorts each line depending on its first element and puts the result in the output file. If the first element is a positive value, the elements of the line must be sorted in descending order. If it's a negative value - in ascending order. If the line starts with `0` then it must just stay the same without changing of the order.

I'm using a bubble sort method for this task, but I can't figure out where exactly to write in an output function in my code... This method assumes that there will be a couple iterations going one by one until the order of all elements will be correct. How can I understand when this exact moment comes? Should I add in my code a bool function or something? Or maybe it's way easier than I'm thinking?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input = fopen("int_numbers.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        printf("An error occurred");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen("result.txt", "w");
    if (output == NULL) {
        printf("An error occurred");
        return 2;
    }

    char line[300];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input) != NULL) {
        int num = sizeof(line) / sizeof(line[0]);

        // sorting in descending order 
        if (line[0] > 0) {
            for (int i = 0, i < num - 1, i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < num - i - 1, j++) {
                    if (line[j] < line[j + 1]) {
                        int tmp = line[j];
                        line[j] = line[j + 1];
                        line[j + 1] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            } 
        } 

        // sorting in ascending order
        if (line[0] < 0) {
            for (int i = 0, i < num - 1, i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < num - i - 1, j++) {
                    if (line[j] > line[j + 1]) {
                        int tmp = line[j + 1];
                        line[j + 1] = line[j];
                        line[j] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

        // no changes in order required
        if (line[0] == 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < num, i++) {
                fputs(line[i], output);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why did you name your input `output` and your output `input`?

Comment: @hobbs Fixed it, sorry :(

Comment: You've written the question in terms of reading input -- and you do need significant work there -- but the actual question seems to be something entirely different.  "*there will be a couple iterations going one by one until the order of all elements will be correct. How can I understand when this exact moment comes?*" -- you know the elements being sorted are in order when your sort algorithm finishes (supposing that it is correct).  So I'm unsure whether you're asking how to write a Bubble Sort correctly, or whether you are making a faulty assumption.

Comment: The for separators are semicolons, not commas.

Comment: fputs expects a pointer to char as its first parameter, not a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work as exposed in the question: instead of sorting *numbers*, you are sorting the characters in the line.

Furthermore `fputs(line[i], output)` has undefined behavior: you pass a single character to `fputs` instead of a C string as expected. Use advanced warnings (eg: **gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror**) to detect and reject silly errors like this.

You should parse the line into an array of `int`, there are at most 30 of them, then sort the array in the desired order, then use `printf` to output the sorted numbers into the output file.  It is unclear whether you are supposed to copy the lines that start with `0` or rewrite them from the array.  It would make a difference for numbers such as `-0`, `00`, `01`... and might also change the spacing.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input = fopen("int_numbers.txt", "r");
    if (input == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s\n", "int_numbers.txt", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen("result.txt", "w");
    if (output == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s\n", "result.txt", strerror(errno));
        fclose(input);
        return 2;
    }

    char line[300];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input) != NULL) {
        /* parse the numbers in the line */
        int numbers[30];
        int num, pos = 0, len;
        for (num = 0; num < 30; num++) {
            if (sscanf(line + pos, "%d%n", &numbers[num], &len) != 1)
                break;
            pos += len;
        }

        if (num == 0) {
            // no numbers, copy the line or strip it out?
            fputs(line, output);
            continue;
        }

        if (numbers[0] > 0) {
            // sorting in descending order
            for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1]) {
                    int tmp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                    numbers[i + 1] = tmp;
                    if (i > 0)
                        i -= 2;
                }
            }
        } else
        if (numbers[0] < 0) {
            // sorting in ascending order
            for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]) {
                    int tmp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                    numbers[i + 1] = tmp;
                    if (i > 0)
                        i -= 2;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // no changes in order required
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            printf("%d%c", numbers[i], " \n"[i == num - 1]);
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```